# Cosa significa "tappa" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel telegiornale di Euronews, in una notizia sulla FIFA, sul comitato esecutivo straordinario previsto per oggi, ho sentito questa frase:

> All’ordine del giorno del comitato la preparazione delle *tappe* per un congresso straordinario per eleggere un nuovo presidente.

Ho cercato la parola ["tappa"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tappa/)  nei dizionari, ma nessuna delle accezioni sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato di "tappe" nella frase precedente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direi che sia un uso figurato del senso militare o di quello ciclistico: il comitato starebbe preparando le fasi, i passaggi intermedi (gli *step*, per usare un anglismo non indispensabile) necessari per arrivare al congresso. Per usare un altro anglismo, è una metafora simile a quella della *roadmap*.

Comment: Certamente è tutto vero, ma non so, mi sembra che con "tappe" in questo contesto ci si riferisca più che a delle figurate "fasi" o "passaggi intermedi" a delle vere e proprie date, i.e. si parla più che altro delle date in cui fissare i punti chiave per la preparazione del congresso (voglio dire in fondo lo sapranno già quali sono queste tappe, non è che devono inventarsele, devono solo fissarle), comunque questa è indubbiamente una sottigliezza un po un'assunzione (quindi forse anche sbagliata), penso stia bene giusto come commento per tentare di precisare un pò il significato nel contesto.

Comment: Comunque rileggendo forse ho letto male io e implicavi proprio questo?

Comment: @kos: No, effettivamente in quello che scrivevo non mi riferivo esplicitamente alle date, ma è ben possibile. Quindi in questo caso le “tappe” sarebbero più o meno sinonimo di “scadenze” da darsi.

Comment: Si è quello che pensavo (nel caso specifico, la tua spiegazione è indubbiamente perfetta in senso generale). Non saprei, magari è questione di come uno la vuole interpretare. Più che altro riflettevo sul fatto che apparentemente le fasi sarebbero note a priori, quindi ci sarebbe piuttosto poco da preparare e molto di più da mettere in pratica, quindi le tappe (per estensione) diventerebbero delle date vere e proprie (in cui svolgere le varie "fasi"). Più che altro viene spontaneo di associare "tappe" a "date" (spero solo nei casi opportuni) ma non so, magari è solo una cosa mia.

Comment: @kos: Interessante: a me “tappa” fa più pensare a punti (geografici o figurati) da raggiungere via via. Non ho la più pallida delle idee di come si organizzi un congresso straordinario della FIFA, ma forse quanto meno la sua straordinarietà fa sì che anche loro debbano chiarirsi le idee su – che so – farlo precedere da riunioni locali, dalla nomina di comitati ad hoc o chissà che altro.

Comment: Ho sentito la notizia anche io. Qui si intendono espressamente l'insieme di operazioni necessarie affinché il congresso possa svolgersi. Quindi la risposta è corretta. Non userei roadmap perché appunto ci si riferisce a step e non all'intero piano d'azioni.

Comment: Comunque rileggendo forse ho preso un abbaglio, nell'associarle a "date" ci ho messo troppo del personale, sta meglio come l'hai descritta tu